# Import Exception Clause (onException) into Camel Spring XML DSL

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel

Is there a way to import an exception clause (**onException**) into Camel Spring XML DSL to use it within the *camelContext*?

It should work something like the *routContext*, which is explained [in the camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-import-routes-from-other-xml-files.html). There you have a file, which contains the *routeContext*, which you can import into your main file and use it in the *camelContext*:

> 

```
<!-- import the routes from another XML file -->
<import resource="myCoolRoutes.xml"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <!-- refer to a given route to be used -->
    <routeContextRef ref="myCoolRoutes"/>

    <!-- we can of course still use routes inside camelContext -->
    <route id="inside">
        <from uri="direct:inside"/>
        <to uri="mock:inside"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

> 

So I want to have a file, lets call it myCoolException.xml, and it should be possible, to import it into my main file. So it would be something like this:

```
<import resource="myCoolException.xml"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <exceptionContextRef ref="myCoolException"/>
    ...

</camelContext>
```

My goal is to modularize my Camel files and don't repeat myself if I want to reuse exception clauses in different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure we can do this. But you can catch and handle the exception and then forward to a common error processing flow. That flow should be accessible by all camel context.

**like,**

```
onException(Exception.class).handled(true).to("direct-vm:commonErrorHandler")
```

You can have common exception handling logic defined in "direct-vm:commonErrorHandler" route. The same way you can have logically grouped multiple direct-vm route to handle your exception in one common place.

Comment: Hey @Gnana Guru, thank you for this suggestion. It seems to be a good idea to me, so I will try it an give you feedback.